# need help on maximize/desktop screen

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, menu

I tried following jquery in my wordpress snippets to close mobile menu with class id(.wpr-close) when screen size is maximized in chrome browser from smaller screen or where screen size is larger than 768px

```
add_action( 'wpr_menu', function(){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).on('resize', function(event){
                $('.wpr_close').click(function(){
        })
</script>
    <?php
} );
```

can any one correct it

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, take a few minute of your time to take the tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour and read "How do I ask a good question?" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You will have much better chances of getting the answer you're looking for if you. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64017413/edit) your question with more details, informations, code, ...etc. Remember we're not next to you. For non-related code questions visit Wordpress Stackexchange @ https://wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: When trying to fix issue like that it's better to add a link to your website, visual screenshots of the problem, and as much details as you can regarding the end result

Comment: I try to execute the code when screen is maximized. thanks